# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in gamekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, gamekit

i just simply trying to use SKEmitterNode and SKSpriteNode
but i'm getting error on second line of my code

```
startfield.position = CGPoint.init(x:0,y:1200)
```

and error is like

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Getting 2 times and also this one

> "does not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT appropriately entitled"

i didn't understand optional concept so because of that i'm not able to solve it ..

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

 var startfield : SKEmitterNode!
 var player : SKSpriteNode!

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
      startfield = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Starfield")
      startfield.position = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 1200)
      startfield.advanceSimulationTime(10)
      self.addChild(startfield)
      startfield.zPosition = -1
        //define Player
    player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shuttle")
    player.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: player.size.height/2 + 20)
    self.addChild(player)
  }

  override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
      // Called before each frame is rendered
  }
}
```

Comment: `SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Starfield")` returns `nil`

Comment: Typo literal `"Starfield"` vs. `"Startfield"`?

Comment: You also have two questions here. One is the `Optional` and the other is the sandbox access. I would search separately for an answer to the sandbox access part or ask about it in another question.

Comment: yes @ColGraff ,I'm also getting an error like "does not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT appropriately entitled" .

Comment: @ColGraff what should i do ?

Comment: Search for the answer and if you can't find one then ask a new question. Asking two questions in one post is not a good idea and is strongly discouraged. Suppose two answers come up, one correct for one question and another for the other. Which do you accept as the answer for this post?

Answer (score 1):

Redeclare your `starfield` variable (mistyped as `startfield`?) such that it allows nil values:

```
var starfield: SKEmitterNode?
```

This is necessary as `SKEmitterNode(fileNamed:)` is an optional initialiser, i. e. one that may return `nil`. Prior to further usage of this variable test if for not being nil, e. g. using a `guard` statement:

```
guard let starfield = starfield else { return }
```

For the remainder of your function `starfield` is non-nil now.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
startfield = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Starfield")
```

Can return a `nil` if the file isn't found but you have it stored in an implicitly-unwrapped `Optional`:

```
var startfield : SKEmitterNode!
```

So the system treats it as non-`nil` but it's really `nil`. Then when you try to assign a property for that `nil`:

```
startfield.position = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 1200)
// should really be: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1200)
```

Everything blows up and you get a fatal error.

Instead, check that the file loads correctly and then do your assignment:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
  // Load the file into a `SKEmitterNode?` and use optional binding 
  // to attempt to unwrap into a `SKEmitterNode`.
  guard let emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Starfield") else {
    // Unwrapping failed, crash with an appropriate message.
    fatalError("File \"Starfield\" not found.")
  }
  // Unwrapping succeeded, continue
  startfield = emitter
  // ...
}
```

The reason it loads into an `SKEmitterNode?` in the first place is due to the loading being performed in a [failable initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID224) inherited from `SKNode`: [init(fileNamed:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483083-init)

```
convenience init?(fileNamed filename: String)
```

[Optional Binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) is when you use the construct `if let` to unwrap an `Optional`.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a variable with a `!` after the type, you make it "implicitly unwrapped". In practice, this means that if the variable is nil and you try to reference it, you crash.

Get rid of the `!` in your declarations.

```
var startfield : SKEmitterNode?
```

And then change your didMove function to use a guard:

```
  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
      startfield = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Starfield")

      guard let startfield = startfield else {
         print("startfield is nil!")
         return
      }
      startfield.position = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 1200)
      startfield.advanceSimulationTime(10)
      self.addChild(startfield)
      startfield.zPosition = -1
        //define Player
    player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shuttle")
    player.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: player.size.height/2 + 20)
    self.addChild(player)
  }
```

Comment: Good catch. Actually, we can't make startField a non-optional without significant rework, since the compiler forces you to assign a non-nil value to all non-optional instance variables in the init. I edited my answer to leave it as an optional and display an error if the call to `SKEmitterNode(fileNamed:)` fails.

Comment: To the OP: Note that your didMove function will create a new SKEmitter note every time it's called. Is that what you want?

Comment: I removed my original comment when you edited since it was no longer relevant. It's up in the air whether or not you want to have the property implicitly-unwrapped or not. It all depends on how necessary the property is to your project. If it's vital then implicitly-unwrapped is good - either fail gracefully or recover with a substitute, if not then a plain `Optional` can work.

Comment: @DuncanC , Im also getting some other error like "does not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT appropriately entitled"